# how does angular 6 consume rest api dynamically through zuul api?

Tags: spring-boot, angular6, spring-cloud, spring-rest, netflix-zuul

I am new to Angular 6.  I consume the Java Rest Api by hard coding in Angular 6 using observe. I am trying to consume Rest Api dynamically using Zuul Gateway api. I not getting idea. How to do it ? Could you please help me anybody  ?

Comment: what have you tried? You haven't provided any details about versions, configuration or steps?

Comment: I am trying to dynamically call the spring rest service through gateway api by Angular 6 client. In Gateway Api I routed the rest service call using Eureka. Like in Eureka server service producer and consumer register itself. And service consumer discover the service and calls as an instance. Can we call the Routed rest service via zuul api as an instance by Angular 6 client to make dynamic call ?

Comment: I don't know how to answer without any configuration to check on our versions